# How to convert a file with several spaces into a tab-delimited file?

Tags: command-line, sed

I had `file1`:

```
MSTRG.10807.1   0.494311896511595   MID    0.423993026403461 2.39379412548345   1.99703339651136
MSTRG.10884.1   0.365770947942799   EARLY  1.46416917664929   1.16816186543633   0.689075392478972
MSTRG.10958.1   0.52855355823638    MID    0.885493751836316  2.28463841550375   1.26867555157512
```

I used command the `sed 's/ /,/g' file1 > file2` and this produced `file2`:

```
MSTRG.10807.1,,,0.494311896511595,,,MID,,,,0.423993026403461,,2.39379412548345,,,1.99703339651136
MSTRG.10884.1,,,0.365770947942799,,,EARLY,,1.46416917664929,,,1.16816186543633,,,0.689075392478972
MSTRG.10958.1,,,0.52855355823638,,,,MID,,,,0.885493751836316,,2.28463841550375,,,1.26867555157512
```

But I want a tab-delimited file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the tab character, use [`\t`](https://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces) as the replace pattern instead of `,`.

If you want just one tab (or comma) to replace multiple spaces, add [`\+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) after the space:

```
sed 's/ \+/\t/g' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `tr`:

```
tr -s ' ' '\t' < file1 > file2
```

> *-s, --squeeze-repeats*
>   replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed in the last specified SET, with a single occurrence of that
>   character